# How do I register an event on a backbone view element..?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to bind a click event on the view's `el` itself. But I'm not able to do so.

One work around is to add an extra element around the actual view content element as the view's `el`.

For example, template:

```
<div> <!-- actual view element -->
  <div id="viewContainer"> <!-- added as dummy for event binding-->
    <div id="viewContent"></div> <!-- actual view content-->
  </div>
</div>
```

and register the event as:

```
events: {"click #viewContainer": "callback"}
```

Is there a way to avoid having this extra `<div>` and bind the events directly to view's `el`..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind the events directly to view's `el`, just avoid the selector part of the event hash and use : `{"event": "callback"}` syntax

For example, template:

```
  <div id="viewContent">...</div> <!-- actual view content-->
```

and register the event as:

```
events: {"click : "callback"}
```

Backbone binds the event directly to the view's element:

```
<div> <!-- actual view element-->
    <div id="viewContent"></div> <!-- actual view content-->
</div>
```

Comment: ["Omitting the `selector` causes the event to be bound to the view's root element (`this.el`)."](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents)

Comment: @muistooshort Yep I know it's there, that part of documentation doesn't seemthat google friendly... I have seen people asking this in my workplace and [in too specific way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34645874/2333214) here...  So I thought i'll post something google friendly :P

Comment: Can't miss a change to mention the *fine manual* can I? The Backbone docs do mention things in odd places though.

Comment: Thanks @T J although ironically I couldn't find this on google and only found it once the question and answer I posted got marked as a duplicate